# No encuentro el Error en mi programa de js

Tags: javascript

hola soy nuevo en la programación, el caso es que estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en realizar un pequeño programa en js que crea historias diferentes al azar, insertando cadenas de texto en la cadena principal, cuando lo voy a ejecutar en la consola del navegador me dice que hay un error en la linea 18, este(main.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.generarHistoria (main.js:18)), de mi código, pero no lo veo, aqui les dejo el codigo y quien me pueda ayudar gracias.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('randomize');
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('story');
const historia = 'Hacía 94 grados Fahrenheit afuera, así que :insertx: salio caminar. Cuando llegaron a :inserty: , miraron con horror por unos momentos, luego :insertz: . Bob lo vio todo, pero no se sorprendió, Bob pesa 300 libras y era un día caluroso.';

var nuevaHistoria = historia;
var intercepcion1 = ['Willy el Duende','Papá grande','Papá Noel'];
var intercepcion2 = ['el comedor de beneficencia','Disneylandia','la casa Blanca'];
var intercepcion3 = ['se quemo espontáneamente','se derritido en un charco en la acera','se convirtió en una babosa y se arrastró lejos'];
var intercepcion123 = [intercepcion1,intercepcion2,intercepcion3];
var intercepciones = [':insertx:',':inserty:',':insertz:'];
        
function generarHistoria(){
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
        var aleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
        nuevaHistoria = nuevaHistoria.replace(intercepciones[i],intercepcion123[i][aleatorio]);
    }
        p.textContent = historia;
        p.style.visibility = 'visible'
}

btn.addEventListener('click' , generarHistoria);
```

```css
  body {
      font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
      width: 350px;
    }

    label {
      font-weight: bold;  
    }

    div {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
      padding: 5px;
      width: 150px;
    }

    p {
      background: #FFC125;
      color: #5E2612;
      padding: 10px;
      visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Generador de Historias Absurdas.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="customname">Ingrese un nombre personalizado:</label>
            <input type="text" id="customname" value="nombre">
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label for="us">US</label>
            <input id="us" type="radio" name="ukus" value="us" checked>
            <label for="uk">UK</label>
            <input id="uk" type="radio" name="ukus" value="uk">
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <button id="randomize">Genera una historia aleatoria</button>
        </div>
        <p class="story"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: al hacer un ```document.getElementById('');``` solo se coloca el ```id``` del elemto y no va con un *#*, deberia de ser ```document.getElementById('randomize');``` y lo mismo para las clases

Answer (score 0):

El comentario de Christian explica donde está el error y como corregirlo. Solo agregaré un poco de explicación adicional:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('#randomize');
```

En esta línea no encuentra el `<button id="randomize">` porque `getElementById` solo necesita el valor del id, por lo que `btn` es `null` y eso causa el error. La forma correcta de usarlo es sin el "#":

```
var btn = document.getElementById('randomize');
```

Lo mismo ocurre con `getElementsByClassName`: esta función requiere el nombre de la clase CSS, sin especificar el ".":

```
//Incorrecto:
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('.story');
//Correcto:
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('story');
```

Adicionalmente, `getElementsByClassName` devuelve un objeto de tipo HTMLCollection, que básicamente es un *array* de elementos que tienen la misma clase, por lo que en tu caso debes recorrer ese array para obtener el div que necesitas (documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

**Actualizado: Una misma alternativa para ambos casos**

Puedes usar `document.querySelector` para ambos casos, pero si es así, el parámetro debe ser un selector CSS, como lo tenías al principio. De esta forma te devolverá un elemento tanto por ID como por Clase:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#randomize');
var p = document.querySelector('.story');
```

Documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector